Add to curly-curly argument
I am trying to take this canonical example for how the curly-curly operator works
mean_by <- function(data, by, var) {
  data %>%
    dplyr::group_by({{ by }}) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(avg = mean({{ var }}, na.rm = TRUE))
}

mtcars %>% mean_by(by = cyl, var = disp)

and modify it by adding an additional variable to the grouping. Alas, I may never understand what that operator actually does; my attempts to do things like
mean_by <- function(data, by, var) {
  data %>%
    dplyr::group_by({{ c(by, hp) }}) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(avg = mean({{ var }}, na.rm = TRUE))
}

mtcars %>% mean_by(by = cyl, var = disp)

clearly aren't working

What is your goal? Do you want the function to group by hp and whatever is passed to by? So in your example group_by(cyl, hp)?

side note: recent short-cut and preferred: dplyr::summarise(avg=mean{{var}}, na.rm=TRUE), .by={{by}}).

@Friede “preferred” by whom? I certainly don’t prefer this shortcut.

That https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_by.html reads like so.

A few years ago dplyr added pick to let people pass off {{}} to data masking functions. So you can do something like this.
library(dplyr)

group_mean = \(data, by, var, ...) {
  data |> 
   group_by(pick({{by}}), ...) |> 
   summarise(mean = mean({{var}}))
}

group_mean(starwars, by = c(homeworld, species), sex, var = mass)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'homeworld', 'species'. You can override
#> using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 64 × 4
#> # Groups:   homeworld, species [57]
#>    homeworld      species   sex     mean
#>    <chr>          <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 Alderaan       Human     female    49
#>  2 Alderaan       Human     male      NA
#>  3 Aleen Minor    Aleena    male      15
#>  4 Bespin         Human     male      79
#>  5 Bestine IV     <NA>      <NA>     110
#>  6 Cato Neimoidia Neimodian male      90
#>  7 Cerea          Cerean    male      82
#>  8 Champala       Chagrian  male      NA
#>  9 Chandrila      Human     female    NA
#> 10 Concord Dawn   Human     male      79
#> # ℹ 54 more rows

Created on 2024-09-18 with reprex v2.1.0

It would be possible to do this using rlang::enquos() to defuse multiple expressions:
dplyr::group_by(hp, !!!rlang::enquos(by))

However, as this Tidyverse blog post states:

If you would like to pass multiple arguments to a data-masking verb, pass ... directly

So in your case, to group by hp and whatever else the caller passes:
mean_by_hp <- function(data, ..., var) {
    data |>
        dplyr::group_by(hp, ...) |>
        dplyr::summarise(avg = mean({{ var }}, na.rm = TRUE))
}


mean_by_hp(mtcars, cyl, var = disp)
#       hp   cyl   avg
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1    52     4  75.7
#  2    62     4 147.
#  3    65     4  71.1
#  4    66     4  78.8
#  5    91     4 120.
#  6    93     4 108
#  7    95     4 141.
#  8    97     4 120.
#  9   105     6 225
# 10   109     4 121


An alternative might be: mean_by = \(data, by, var) dplyr::summarise(data, avg = mean({{var}}, na.rm = TRUE), .by={{by}});  mtcars |> mean_by(by=cyl, var=disp); mtcars |> mean_by(by=c(cyl, hp), var=disp)? I.e. doing by=c(cyl, hp).

@Friede it's surprising to me that you can pass c(cyl, hp) to summarise(.by = {{by}}) but not group_by({{by}}). I don't want to include it in my answer as I don't know why it works (and frankly I prefer ... over this NSE stuff because it tends to have fewer surprises). But your suggestion does work - perhaps you should post as an answer.

I was suprised too. I hesitate since I do not know if OP wants to pass arguments to several {dplyr}-functions or just summarise. The downside in my opinion is that ... cannot be used elsewhere then.

It seems like ..  dplyr::group_by(data, across({{by}})) |> dplyr::summarise(avg = mean({{var}}, na.rm = TRUE)) .. is a work-around.

@Friede I'm beginning to regret answering this question - once again I'm reminded that though I think I understand R better than most other languages, under the hood I basically have no idea what's going on

There are two different basic argument passing mechanisms in dplyr:  select syntax and data-masking syntax.  the .by= argument uses select syntax (from package tidyselect) and group_by(...) uses data masking syntax.  You have to look at the help files to know which is used where.

@G.Grothendieck I see! I think dplyr is a great package from a theoretical perspective but in practice it tends to be noticeably slower than alternatives, and I don't actually use it that much, and the distinction between select syntax and data masking had completely eluded me - useful to know, thanks.

@SamR, dplyr can work with a data.table input which might be faster.  Also there is a package, tidytable that uses data.table as the backend but with dplyr syntax which might be faster.
